# Proving that a positive definite matrix has positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I came across a question in my homework that I'm sure is easier than I'm making out to be, but it's stumping me nonetheless (this is in an undergraduate Linear Algebra class using Strang's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, 4e).

"If a 2 by 2 symmetric matrix passes the tests $a>0$, $ac>b^2$, solve the quadratic equation $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ and show that both eigenvalues are positive." (Strang 4e, section 6.1, no. 3)

This is as far as I've gotten:

Let $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
b & c \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\det(A-\lambda I)=
\begin{vmatrix}
a-\lambda & b \\
b & c-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=(a-\lambda)(c-\lambda)-b^2=0$, which simplifies to $\lambda^2-(a+c)\lambda+ac-b^2=0$. Applying the quadratic formula, we then have $$
\lambda=\frac{a+c\pm\sqrt{(a+c)^2-4(ac-b^2)}}{2} \\
 = \frac{a+c\pm\sqrt{(a-c)^2+4b^2}}{2} \\$$

Now I just need to show that both of those roots are positive. $a$ and $(a-c)^2+4b^2$ are both trivially positive, and I've found that $c$ is positive as well. I think I would have to show that $a+c\phantom{|}\gt\sqrt{(a-c)^2+4b^2}$, but that's where I'm drawing a blank. Any ideas?

Those conditions in the problem mean that $A$ is positive definite, but I'm not sure how to use that fact to my advantage.

Thanks from a brand-new StackExchange user!

Comment: Everything is correct. For the last inequality, squaring both sides and simplifying gives $ac > b^2$, which is one of your hypotheses.

Comment: @LukePeachey That was exactly the kind of simple step I thought I was missing; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that inequality, square both sides: $$(a + c)^2 = (a - c)^2 + 4ac > (a - c)^2 + 4b^2.$$